Formating the date with bootstrap datepicker
I have an input where using bootstrap datepicker, but i want the output format to be like (Day - Month #, year)
ex: Wednesday - January 1, 2025.
<div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label>Date</label>
  <div class="date input-group">
   <input
    type="text"
    class="datepicker form-control"
    id="date-input"
   />
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


here is my script for updating the input value
$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#date-input").datepicker({
                    format: "mm/dd/yyyy", 
                    autoclose: true,
                });

                $(".datepicker").on("changeDate", function (e) {
                    const selectedDate = e.date; // Get selected date as JavaScript Date object
                    const options = { weekday: "long", year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric" };
                    const formattedDate = selectedDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);

$("#date-input").datepicker("update", formattedDate); 
                });
            });

but it does not update the input value. but it shows a correct output on my console.log

You gave the format: "mm/dd/yyyy" in datepicker.
If you want (Day - Month #, year), just change it to the following the documentation.
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format.
format: "DD - MM d, yyyy"

never thought of this is valid.

You can use toDisplay function, to achieve [custom] format what you need.


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#date-input").datepicker({
    format: {
      toDisplay: function(date, format, language) {
        const options = {
          weekday: "long",
          month: "long",
          day: "numeric",
          year: "numeric"
        };
        return new Date(date).toLocaleDateString("en-US", options).replace(",", " -");
      },
      toValue: function(date, format, language) {
        return new Date(date);
      },
    },
    autoclose: true,
  });
});
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="date-input">Date</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="date-input" placeholder="Select a date" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0pUGZvbkm6XF6gxjEnlmuGrJXVbNuzT9qBBavbLwCsOGabYfZo0T0to5eqruptLy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha512-LsnSViqQyaXpD4mBBdRYeP6sRwJiJveh2ZIbW41EBrNmKxgr/LFZIiWT6yr+nycvhvauz8c2nYMhrP80YhG7Cw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>




In your changeDate function you need to add the formatted date in the input the update function doesn't set the input value
// Set the formatted date to the input field
    $("#date-input").val(formattedDate);

This will solve your issue

Replace
$("#date-input").datepicker("update", formattedDate); with $("#date-input").val(formattedDate);

The datepicker("update") method expects a date object or formatted date string compatible with the datepicker's format
.val() directly sets the input's value to the formatted date string
If you want to maintain the underlying date value for form submission while showing the formatted text, you can use a hidden input
